# Intersection of two polyline geometries not returning expected coordinates?

Tags: arcpy, point

```
T2B = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(1,2),arcpy.Point(-1, -2)]) 
L2R = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(0, 2), arcpy.Point(1, -2)]) 
L2R_line = arcpy.Polyline(L2R) 
T2B_line = arcpy.Polyline(T2B) 
cent = L2R_line.intersect(T2B_line, 1)
arcpy.AddMessage("X co_ordinate "+str(cent.X))
```

I am trying to find intersection of two polylines.  Here is my sample code 
But this is not printing x coordinate of intersection point.  I would like to know how to get x and y coordinates from "cent" object.

Answer (score 3):

This looks familiar!

The issue you're having is that the result of cent is a multipoint geometry instead of just a point geometry- even though the result of the intersect IS a single point. I'm not sure if a multipoint is always returned or what.

You might try something like this:

```
T2B = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(1,2),arcpy.Point(-1, -2)]) 
L2R = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(0, 2), arcpy.Point(1, -2)]) 
L2R_line = arcpy.Polyline(L2R) 
T2B_line = arcpy.Polyline(T2B) 
cent = L2R_line.intersect(T2B_line, 1)
for point in cent:
  arcpy.AddMessage("X coordinate "+str(point.X))
  arcpy.AddMessage("Y coordinate "+str(point.Y))
```

Or this would work too:

```
T2B = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(1,2),arcpy.Point(-1, -2)]) 
L2R = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(0, 2), arcpy.Point(1, -2)]) 
L2R_line = arcpy.Polyline(L2R) 
T2B_line = arcpy.Polyline(T2B) 
cent = L2R_line.intersect(T2B_line, 1)
arcpy.AddMessage("X coordinate "+str(cent.firstPoint.X))
arcpy.AddMessage("Y coordinate "+str(cent.firstPoint.Y))
```